# Plotting 95% confidence bands in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset and would like to plot a line graph in R with 95% confidence bands.

```
rr_preterm  lower_ci    upper_ci    time
1.409273982 1.118492961 1.775650024 1
1.114063978 0.901437819 1.376845002 2
0.849429905 0.717030287 1.006276965 3
0.789976776 0.660233378 0.945216298 4
1.021203041 0.7967695   1.308853984 5
```

time variable as '`x`' and `rr_preterm` as '`y`'. can anybody help me please?

Comment: please post a reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far? SO is to help.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show us what your data looks like.

Comment: Look into `geom_ribbon` in the ggplot docs

Comment: are `lower_ci` and `upper_ci` the limits of your 95% confidence bands?

Comment: The other votes were close for "Too broad", but I agreed with @ patrickmdnet that this was most likely answered in the 2012  BBolker'a reply.